# How to provide a smtp server for solicited promotional email?

Tags: smtp, blacklist

I have a customer who needs to send some direct mailing to his contacts which is being collected from trade shows etc. I am thinking about providing a web based solution for them on sending direct mailing material- however this kind of solution always face a major difficulty on having the server blacklisted. I would like to know if there is any suggestions on how to maintain such SMTP server?

Answer (score 5):

- Have your SMTP server respond to HELO/EHLO commands with your specific DNS name, not generic IP nor generic reversal (YES: mail.example.com ; NO: 1.2.3.4 , 4-3-2-1.dsl.example.com )
- Have a Reverse DNS matching the HELO response (example: nslookup mail.example.com -> 1.2.3.4, nslooup 1.2.3.4 -> mail.example.com)
- Make sure nobody but legit users can send emails, no open relays or forwarders!
- Have the mandatory email addresses correctly delivered (abuse, postmaster and info, IIRC), and that the reply-to address of the email exists and are regularly checked (repeatedly sending to dead email addresses can incur in blacklisting)
- Check that double opt-in is in use for internet-driven subscriptions
- Also make sure opt-out is working
- Have a clear disclaimer

And, just in case:
- Make sure the IP address of the SMTP is different from your other SMTPs, so in case something fail you're still able to send mails from other accounts!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the server (just set up exim or postfix and a web interface to send newsletters from, and do this on a server with an IP address that is different from your own personal mail server (maybe even a different network)), you will want to get your terms and conditions of use nice and tight so that you can remove access to the systems from any customer that has complaints made about emailing. Indeed you can mandate that all emails sent must be lawful (e.g., unsubscription option that works, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo has some best practice guidelines for bulk mailing. They are also good general best practices to follow when sending mails to other mail servers also.

You can find them at

[Best practices when sending to Yahoo! Mail](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/postmaster-15.html)

[Guidelines for establishing SMTP connections to Yahoo! Mail](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/postmaster-277515.html)